# Cannot Create ActiveX Component error on export to excel from ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, excel

On trying to export through excel in ASP.net Web application i get the following error Cannot create ACTIVEX Component.

Have searched few answers and solved this by using bits and pieces from every answer. I would like to seggregate into one , so that anyone who is looking for a  similar solution can get benefited.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when i tried to export excel from my web site i got the error 'Cannot Create ActiveX Component'. I tried a solution where i have to go to properties of microsoft excel application in component services.

But i did not find 'Microsoft Excel application in Adminitative tools -> Component Services -> Computers -> MyComputer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application.

**Solution for Cannot Create ActiveX Component error:**

Go to Start -> Run -> mmc -32 -> File -> Add/Remove Snap-in -> Component Services -> Add -> OK.

After adding component services to the console root you will be able to find 'Microsoft Excel Application' when you navigate as below

Console Root -> Component Services -> Computer -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application

Right click Microsoft Excel Application -> Properties -> Security Tab -> In Access Permissions, click "Edit Defaults" and add Network Service to it and give it "Allow local access" permission. Do the same for \Users. In launch and Activation Permissions, click "Edit Defaults" and add Network Service to it and give it "Local launch" and "Local Activation" permission. Do the same for \Users

Now your ActiveX Component Error will be resolved.

After this i encountered another error where Microsoft Excel is not able to access the html file created to change it to excel.